# How well does next.js 13.4.9 handle data-fetching?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I am new to Next.js and I want to know, What new data fetching patterns have been explored by Next.js 13.4.9? How well does dynamic data fetching work?

For example, if you wanted to fetch some data, the original version of Next.js looked like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import 'isomorphic-fetch';
 
export default class extends React.Component {
  static async getInitialProps() {
    const resp = await fetch('https://api.company.com/user/12345');
    const data = await resp.json();
    return { username: data.profile.username };
  }
}
```

What new data fetching patterns have been explored by Next.js 13.4.9?

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching.

You don't need to import `fetch` from any external library. Rather, you should not. Next.js takes care of that.

Comment: response time is high of my component, i think thats because of api call, is it not supposed to be fast